# Prometheus/ create list of tag from __meta_gce_tags

Tags: regex, prometheus

Im using [relabeling](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/operating/configuration.md#relabel_config) in order to take the gce tag to Prometheus labels, by using the following code in Prometheus yml:

```
 relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_gce_tags]
    target_label: tags
```

the tags look like this:

```
tags=",node_a,node_prod,node_centos,"
```

The problem is that it gives a string list, while I wish to have list of tags so I can query it. for example, instead of using:

```
sum(elasticsearch_node_stats_up{tags=~".*?noda_a.*node_prod.?"})
```

I will be able to use it without regex. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract values from a label value during relabeling. So try this, which is not exactly DRY, but works:

```
relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_gce_tags]
    regex: ",node_([a-z]+),node_[a-z]+,node_[a-z]+"
    target_label: node
    replacement: '${1}'
  - source_labels: [__meta_gce_tags]
    regex: ",node_[a-z]+,node_([a-z]+),node_[a-z]+"
    target_label: env
    replacement: '${1}'
  - source_labels: [__meta_gce_tags]
    regex: "",node_[a-z]+,node_[a-z]+,node_([a-z]+)""
    target_label: os
    replacement: '${1}'
```

Note that there is probably a much more elegant regular expression to use.

If you can control the label values, here is a much more durable technique: https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-full-labels-from-consul-tags/